# Printing zone plate with laser printer

Tags: optics, visible-light, experimental-physics, home-experiment, diffraction

I tried to print my own zone plates on transparent plastic with laser printer with [this generator](http://www.whizkidtech.redprince.net/zoneplate/). I prepared a [lot of plates](https://dl.dropbox.com/s/td3jifkquiwm6kj/zoneplates.png) with different settings - focus from 4 to 60 cm, 3 wave lengths, etc.

Yet no matter how I look through plates or how I try to focus light with them I see no lens-like behavior.

The sizes of printed plates seems to be OK. It looks like printer smoothered details a little - megapinholes lost small orifices. But when I look at zones through magnifying lens it seems OK - a lot of concentric circles with decreasing width. Even if there are some errors it would mean that plate should concentrate most of light, right?

If the reason is bad printer calibration then my plates for red light should work as blue light plates or vice versa. If xy-calibration is wrong and it makes circles into ovals then it should work if I incline it a little.

So I have no idea what is the problem and how resolve it.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/155216/possibility-of-making-an-experiment-in-a-classroom-to-simulate-dna-diffraction. I haven't gone beyond simple linear diffraction gratings at this point, but they work. However, the first maxima angles are very small ($1$—$2 \,\mathrm{mrad}$).